# How to Persist a Map in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, persistence

I am stuck at the following problem.

The following is my Entity OrderModel. I have another entity named ItemModel, which I want to use in a Map. I want to book orders.

For each Item I select for an order I want to specify the number of such items, and hence the integer in the map. The key ofcourse must be the Item Object.

Here is the OrderModel.

```
    package com.project.pms.model;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.MapKey;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

    @Entity
    public class OrderModel
    {
        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private Long orderId;

        private String orderReferenceNumber;

        @OneToOne
        private ClientModel orderedBy;

        @OneToOne
        private ClientModel orderedTo;

        @OneToMany
        @MapKey(name="THE_ITEM")
        private Map<ItemModel,Integer> itemList= new HashMap<ItemModel, Integer>();
        // the integer above depicts the quantity of the Item
        // For each Item I select I need to specify how many of those

        private String orderIssuedDate;

        private String orderToBeCompletedBy;

        private String totalPaymentToBeMade;

        private String orderState;

        public Long getOrderId()
        {
            return orderId;
        }

        public void setOrderId(Long orderId)
        {
            this.orderId = orderId;
        }

        public String getOrderReferenceNumber()
        {
            return orderReferenceNumber;
        }

        public void setOrderReferenceNumber(String orderReferenceNumber)
        {
            this.orderReferenceNumber = orderReferenceNumber;
        }

        public ClientModel getOrderedBy()
        {
            return orderedBy;
        }

        public void setOrderedBy(ClientModel orderedBy)
        {
            this.orderedBy = orderedBy;
        }

        public ClientModel getOrderedTo()
        {
            return orderedTo;
        }

        public void setOrderedTo(ClientModel orderedTo)
        {
            this.orderedTo = orderedTo;
        }

        public Map<ItemModel, Integer> getItemList()
        {
            return itemList;
        }

        public void setItemList(Map<ItemModel, Integer> itemList)
        {
            this.itemList = itemList;
        }

        public String getOrderIssuedDate()
        {
            return orderIssuedDate;
        }

        public void setOrderIssuedDate(String orderIssuedDate)
        {
            this.orderIssuedDate = orderIssuedDate;
        }

        public String getOrderToBeCompletedBy()
        {
            return orderToBeCompletedBy;
        }

        public void setOrderToBeCompletedBy(String orderToBeCompletedBy)
        {
            this.orderToBeCompletedBy = orderToBeCompletedBy;
        }

        public String getTotalPaymentToBeMade()
        {
            return totalPaymentToBeMade;
        }

        public void setTotalPaymentToBeMade(String totalPaymentToBeMade)
        {
            this.totalPaymentToBeMade = totalPaymentToBeMade;
        }

        public String getOrderState()
        {
            return orderState;
        }

        public void setOrderState(String orderState)
        {
            this.orderState = orderState;
        }







    }
```

However I am getting the following exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.project.pms.service.ClientService.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.project.pms.model.OrderModel.itemList[java.lang.Integer]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:67)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)



root cause 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.project.pms.service.ClientService.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.project.pms.model.OrderModel.itemList[java.lang.Integer]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework
```

Is there a way I can persist the numberOfItems Integer with the type of Item.
Of course I do not require this field in the ItemModel itself.

Also can someone answer my QueryByExample question as well:)
It would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `targeting an unmapped class: com.project.pms.model.OrderModel.itemList[java.lang.Integer]`

Comment: what does this mean Eddie, If I use a mapped class even then what should be my approach? Can you help?

Comment: You don't need a mapkey for this... Just use a `@OneToMany` and the 'count' will be automatically generated when you add a new item.

Comment: For a very good example check out [Spring Restbucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks)

Answer (score 0):

To persist collections in JPA2 you can use @ElementCollection

For more refer : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html

Comment: Can you please be verbose. I am not sure how I can apply element collection to my problem set, both are models.